# Is this normal for AngularJs filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty much new to angular, but I feel like this is kind of crazy.

I've got multiple collections being displayed via ng-repeat in one controller scope. There's an input field for each list to perform a simple query. I was playing around with various filters in my code and I ended up putting a console.log in my filter function. I realized that every time my filter function was called for one list, it was being called for all of the lists in the scope. Furthermore, it was calling the filter function twice each time. So with 3 collections, filtering one of the lists would call the filter function 6 times.

I thought maybe it was just my custom filter, so I tried it out on the default filter function. Same story. Here's my code:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/905197/angular-filter-test.html

Go to the console and see for yourself :/

What am I doing wrong here? This seems like such a simple thing but it's doing so much work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is normal, angularjs uses a 'dirty-check' approach, so it needs to call all the filters to see if  any changes exist. After this it detects that you have a change on one variable (the one that you typed) and then it re-executes all filters again to detect if it has other changes.

See the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) question

Comment: Interesting. That explains why all of them are getting called. Now why do all of them get called twice each time a change has happened?

Comment: The first call is from the watchers that are detecting the change. Because there is one then they need to be called again to see if is there news changes because a watcher can make changes. This process will be repeated until no changes are found or the 'loop' reach the number of max interactions(I think that is 10).

Comment: How to avoid this? i do a json call but it may be called up to 10 times by just clicking anywhere.