# angular ng-repeat fires many times than expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Function key_helper gets called many more times than expected.if orderedkeys length is 5 it gets called 25 times instead of 5 times  .I am not sure what code to incluce for better understating of my problem.how to make sure it .doesn't repeat

Template:

```
<td  ng-repeat="key in orderedkeys" >
<div>{{Key_Helper(key)}}</div>
</td>
```

I tried with a filter:(same problem)

```
 <td  ng-repeat="key in orderedkeys" >
 <div>{{key | debug}}</div>
 </td>
```

Function:

```
$scope.Key_Helper = function(item)
{     
  console.log("key");    
};
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973792/why-angularjs-will-invoke-function-name-twice

Comment: how to make sure it doesnt call digest cycle again

Answer (score 2):

The expression `{{}}` in not actual `JavaScript`, this is [angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). The `angular expression` allow you to call `$scope` method and `$filter` as well.

If any function call occur inside expression then it will execute two times, at first it call the function and second time on the next [digest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$digest) cycle and **angular works this way**. `$filter` is a function call. It is better to use simple `expression` like `{{1+1}}` or simply value `{{key}}`. You can check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973792/why-angularjs-will-invoke-function-name-twice), [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676901/is-this-normal-for-angularjs-filtering) for better understanding.