# Using a custom filter with ng-bind-html in Angular JS causes the filter function to be called twice

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
      <div ng-bind="welcomeText | wrap"></div> <!-- ng-bind hits filter once -->
      <div ng-bind-html="welcomeText | wrap"></div> <!-- ng-bind-html hits filter twice -->
      <div>Hit count: {{hitCount.count}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var hitCount = { count: 0 };

angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller("controller", [ "$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.hitCount = hitCount;
        $scope.welcomeText = "Hello";
    }])
    .filter("wrap", function($sce) {
        return function(input) {
            hitCount.count++;
            return $sce.trustAsHtml("[" + input + "]");
        };
    });
```

`ng-bind` causes the filter function to be called once, as I'd expect.

However, `ng-bind-html` causes the filter function to be called twice.

Is there a reason for this, or is this a bug?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyVB7yJk0BIxmFNUy8uq?p=preview

Comment: no its not a bug,it is normal ,it because angular do the dirty checking.
please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676901/is-this-normal-for-angularjs-filtering

Comment: OK, fair enough - thank you :) I'm still unclear as to why ng-bind-html does this but ng-bind doesn't, but at least you've answered my question of whether or not it's a bug.