# AngularJs Filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm writing a module, using a custom filter, and I noticed something weird. if I use `console.log()` inside a filter, it logs the value twice, even though I call it only once. Is there a way to log it only once? Does that mean the code inside the filter gets executed twice?

Here's the filter:

```
.filter('arrayToSentence', function($sce, $rootScope) {
    return function(array, index) {
        console.log(index);
        var i, word, sentence = '<span style="color:red;">';
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i < array.length - 1) {
                sentence += array[i] + '&bnsp;';
            } else {
                sentence += array[i];
            }
        }
        sentence = sentence += '</span>'
        return $sce.sentence;
    }
})
```

The `console.log(index)` is logging twice. I need to make sure that my filter logic will not be duplicating anywhere, as further down I need to compare two arrays (the one being filtered, and another one to colour the differences between them, like missing word, or word mismatch).

[EDIT]
It is pointed out to me that my question is a duplicate, of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676901/is-this-normal-for-angularjs-filtering)
Yet the original question doesn't answer how to avoid this issue, but I believe @defaultcheckbox provided a fulfilling answer.

Comment: Can you include an example where this happens?

Comment: where you calling this filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this normal for AngularJs filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676901/is-this-normal-for-angularjs-filtering)

Comment: `<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in sentenceList">
        {{ x.text | arrayToSentence:$index }}<br/>
        <md-button ng-click="viewSentence($index, 'correctSentence', currentUser)" ng-if="x.proper[0]!=null || currentUser=='Teacher'">Correct</md-button>
        </li> 
    </ul>`
This is the part of the HTML that calls the filter.

Comment: @yeouuu I didn't find that duplicate, thank you for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the filter in the DOM with piping, or are you using it in the controller? Using a filter in the DOM will always be "slower" than using one in the controller, but more importantly (and possibly related to your case) DOM filters always run twice.

source: https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/

Comment: Yes I am using the filter in the DOM, I need to figure out how to put it into the controller, thank you for this.